# Deleting Decision Points without losing activities after it

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a decision point at the beginning of my journey to allow only certain contacts to reach the end of my journey, now that I have completed testing I'd like to get rid of the decision point, however simply deleting it removes the rest of the journey.

How can I safely remove this without removing the rest of my journey? I have tried moving the decision point to the end of the journey, but I am shown a red X marker anywhere I try to move it.

**Update**: It appears not being able to move the decision split to the end of the journey is new behaviour in the January 2018 release, prior to this it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain but I usually drag the activities that were after the decision split to before it, leaving the decision at the end without actually moving the decision itself. You can then delete it without losing the rest of your activities. Would love to know if there is another way though.

Comment: I have spoken with SF Support and this indeed in the only way to complete this, they for some reason have removed the ability to move the decision points in the latest release.